# Bernoulli's Inequality when $-2≤x<-1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Why is it that Bernoulli inequality $(1+x)^r>1+rx$ is said to be true for every integer $r≥0$ and every real $x≥-1$; why the range $-2≤x<-1$ is not included?

It seems that, by induction (or other ways), it can also be proved for $x≥-2$. Maybe I am wrong but have not found a counterexample of this inequality for values between $-2$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're talking about the version of Bernoulli for nonnegative integers $r$:  $(1+x)^r \ge 1 + r x$.  Indeed, for $r=1$ this is true for 
all real $x$, while for $r \ge 2$ and $-1 \ge x \ge -2$ we have $(1+x)^r \ge -1$  while $1+rx \le 1-r$.

Of course, the version for real $r$ makes no sense for $x < -1$, because $(1+x)^r$ is not real in general.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clearer in the original question. Yes I was referring to that version: $\left( 1+x\right)^{r}\geq 1+rx$ for every integer $r\geq 0$ and every real $x\geq -1$. As you stated for $r\geq 2$ and $-1\geq x\geq -2$ we have $\left( 1+x\right)^{r}\geq -1$. For this range of negative values of $x$, $1+xr$ is decreasing in $r$, and its max. is (when $x=-1$, $r=2$) $-1$. Then it's also true that $\left( 1+x\right) ^{r}\geq 1+xr$ when $-1\geq x\geq -2$. However I have always seen that the statement only considers $x\geq -1$ so I don't yet see why the range $-1\geq x\geq -2$ is not included